# Crafting System for Survival Game with Batch

Tags: batch

So I've started getting familiar with Batch for the last year off and on, all self taught, and I've made a few little dinky projects here and there but I'm wanting to find out the best way to go about expanding my code. Using other programs for inspiration I've learned just the tip of the icebergs for "FOR loops" and using functions and small macro processes. I want to know if there is anything I should do differently in terms of architecture and planning so I can one day make amazing Batch programs like a this one by T3RROR https://stackoverflow.com/a/66338962/19387135.

````
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
title crafting micro
color 2
:://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:pre_start
::initializes at the start of the program
set /a display_message=0
set /a inv_fiber=1
set /a fiber_qty=100
set /a inv_rope=0
set /a rope_qty=0
set /a inv_stick=1
set /a stick_qty=100
set /a inv_stone=1
set /a stone_qty=100
set /a inv_sharpened_stone=0
set /a sharpened_stone_qty=0
set /a inv_spear=0
set /a spear_qty=0
set /a inv_handaxe=0
set /a handaxe_qty=0
set /a inv_hammer=0
set /a hammer_qty=0
:://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:start
cls
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo         Crafting Menu
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo Raw materials
echo -------------
if %inv_fiber%==1 echo Fiber: x%fiber_qty%
if %inv_stick%==1 echo Stick: x%stick_qty%
if %inv_stone%==1 echo Stone: x%stone_qty%
echo.
echo Refined Materials
echo -----------------
if %inv_rope%==1 echo Rope: x%rope_qty%
if %inv_sharpened_stone%==1 echo Sharpened Stone: x%sharpened_stone_qty%
echo.
echo Tools
echo -----
if %inv_spear%==1 echo Spear: x%spear_qty%
if %inv_handaxe%==1 echo Handaxe: x%handaxe_qty%
if %inv_hammer%==1 echo Hammer: x%hammer_qty%
::sets visibility
echo.
echo ----------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo What do you wanna craft?
echo 1. Rope (x3 Fiber)
echo 2. Sharpened Stone (x2 Stones)
echo 3. Spear (x1 Rope, x1 Stick, x1 Sharpened Stone )
echo 4. Handaxe (x2 Rope, x2 Stick, x1 Sharpened Stone)
echo 5. Hammer (x2 Rope, x2 Stick, x1 Stone)
echo.
choice /c 12345
echo.
echo.

if %errorlevel%==1 (
    set item=Rope
    ::item being crafted
    set /a req1=%fiber_qty%
    ::1st required item
    set /a min1=3
    :: minimum amount needed to craft
    set /a req2=0
    set /a min2=0
    set /a req3=0
    set /a min3=0
    set var1=fiber
    ::passes a string to be use for a vavriable
    set var2=
    set var3=
    set var4=rope
)
if %errorlevel%==2 (
    set item='Sharpened Stone'
    set /a req1=%stone_qty%
    set /a min1=2
    set /a req2=0
    set /a min2=0
    set /a req3=0
    set /a min3=0
    set var1=stone
    set var2=
    set var3=
    set var4=sharpened_stone
)
if %errorlevel%==3 (
    set item=Spear
    set /a req1=%rope_qty%
    set /a min1=1
    set /a req2=%stick_qty%
    set /a min2=1
    set /a req3=%sharpened_stone_qty%
    set /a min3=1
    set var1=rope
    set var2=stick
    set var3=sharpened_stone
    set var4=spear
)
if %errorlevel%==4 (
    set item=Handaxe
    set /a req1=%rope_qty%
    set /a min1=2
    set /a req2=%stick_qty%
    set /a min2=2
    set /a req3=%sharpened_stone_qty%
    set /a min3=1
    set var1=rope
    set var2=stick
    set var3=sharpened_stone
    set var4=handaxe
)
if %errorlevel%==5 (
    set item=Hammer
    set /a req1=%rope_qty%
    set /a min1=2
    set /a req2=%stick_qty%
    set /a min2=2
    set /a req3=%stone_qty%
    set /a min3=1
    set var1=rope
    set var2=stick
    set var3=stone
    set var4=hammer
)
::////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:craftable_check
if %req1% GEQ %min1% (  
    if %req2% GEQ %min2% (
        if %req3% GEQ %min3% (
        ::checks minimum requried material inventory for crafting
            set /a %var1%_qty=!%var1%_qty!-%min1%
            set /a %var2%_qty=!%var2%_qty!-%min2%
            set /a %var3%_qty=!%var3%_qty!-%min3%
            ::uses all the required inventory for crafting
            set /a %var4%_qty=!%var4%_qty!+1
            ::creates the crafted item
            set /a inv_%var4%=1
            ::makes the new item is visible
            if %req1% LEQ 0 (
                set inv_%var1%=0
            )
            if %req2% LEQ 0 (
                set inv_%var2%=0
            )
            if %req3% LEQ 0 (
                set inv_%var3%=0
            )
            ::makes the items ivisible if there is no inventory
            set /a display_message=1
            set message='You have successfully created a %item%!'
            goto message
        )
    )
)
set /a display_message=1
set message=You dont have enough material for this
goto message
:://///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:message
cls
if %display_message%==1 (
    echo %message%
    pause
    set /a display_message=0
    goto start
)
```
````

Comment: Hi dean, are you still working on this project?

Comment: I am lol and several of its chaotic variations. Sorry for the long delay in messaging